# How to print R results in an updatable graphics device?

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk, gwidgets

I'm working on a project involving time series analysis and to make it more user friendly for people not keen on R I'm working on GUI through the packages `gWidgets` and `RGtk2`.

I've already set up an initial user interface selecting data and date to analyse. The results are now printed on the R consolle.

Is there any method for printing results (almost all in a `data.frame` format) in some part of the GUI or generating some xternal graphics device as `hist(data)`.

What I also want my results to be is that they have to be updatable.

Any hints?

Take for example the following code generating the plot of a histogram of m realizations of ¯ xn for
a random sample of size n from the exponential distribution.

```
w = gwindow("Simple GUI")
g = ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, cont=w)
gp = ggroup(cont = g)
glabel("No. simulations (m)", cont=gp)
mWidget = gslider(from=10,to=250,by=10, cont=gp,
expand=TRUE, handler=makePlot)
gp = ggroup(cont = g)
glabel("Size of sample (n)", cont=gp)
nWidget = gedit("5", cont=gp, coerce.with=as.numeric,
handler=makePlot)

gbutton("New sample", cont=g, handler = makePlot)

makePlot = function(...) {
n = svalue(nWidget); m = svalue(mWidget)
x = matrix(rexp(n*m), nrow=n)
res = apply(x, 2, mean)
hist(res)
}
```

How can we have for example some statistics printed on a graphic device?

Comment: there are several functions to display text or tables in graphic devices, e.g. `gridExtra::grid.table`, `gplots::textplot`, `text()`, etc. Would that help?

Comment: Which package do you reccommend based on your experience?

Comment: i'm slightly biased against gridExtra, it's a pain to maintain the package ;)

Comment: there's also `plotrix::addtable2plot`. One thing you might want to consider is whether to use grid or base graphics, btw.

Comment: I do not want to add a table on a plot, just print a table in a graphic device as gridExtra does

Comment: that's pretty much equivalent; you can always issue a `plot.new()` and add a table to that empty canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The package `gridExtra` contains a function called `grid.table` which performs what I mean.

Below a link to "Adding a table to a Grid plot" which explains ghow this function works:

http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-grid:table